# Convert a list of maps to a single map using key from inner map

Tags: elixir

I have two list of maps that look like this:

```
list_one = [
  %{id: :a, value: 1},
  %{id: :b, value: 2},
  %{id: :c, value: 3}
]


list_two = [
  %{id: :a, value: 1},
  %{id: :b, value: 4},
  %{id: :d, value: 5}
]
```

and I know the following:

- `id`s are unique in each list
- `id's are always atoms, values are always integers
- the same `id`s might appear in both lists
- each list might contain some `id` that does not appear in the other
- no maps in either list have more or less keys

I wish to merge those in a single map, with the values from the inner map's `id` as key and the two values if present, or a "null value" (let's say 0) if one of the two lists does not contain one of the `ids` (this last thing is optional). The desired output for the above example would be:

```
%{
  a: %{
    value_one: 1,
    value_two: 1
  },
  b: %{
    value_one: 2,
    value_two: 4
  },
  c: %{
    value_one: 3,
    value_two: 0
  },
  d: %{
    value_one: 0,
    value_two: 5
  }
}
```

I know I could do this by doing a couple of `Enum.reduce` but it feels like I'm missing something easier

Answer (score 3):

I would first convert the lists into maps of the desired shape using [`Map.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/2), and then merge them together using [`Map.merge/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#merge/3):

```elixir
def merge(list_one, list_two) do
  a =
    Map.new(list_one, fn %{id: id, value: value_one} ->
      {id, %{value_one: value_one, value_two: 0}}
    end)

  b =
    Map.new(list_two, fn %{id: id, value: value_two} ->
      {id, %{value_one: 0, value_two: value_two}}
    end)

  Map.merge(a, b, fn _id, %{value_one: value_one}, %{value_two: value_two} ->
    %{value_one: value_one, value_two: value_two}
  end)
end
```

Output:

```elixir
%{
  a: %{value_one: 1, value_two: 1},
  b: %{value_one: 2, value_two: 4},
  c: %{value_one: 3, value_two: 0},
  d: %{value_one: 0, value_two: 5}
}
```

Comment: Smart last `Map.merge/3`, I didn’t figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to transform lists into maps for instant `O(log N)` access later.

```elixir
[map_one, map_two] =
  Enum.map([list_one, list_two], fn list ->
    for %{id: id, value: value} <- list, into: %{}, do: {id, value}
  end)
```

Then, you need to get all the keys upfront, otherwise, there is no way to figure out where we need zeroes added.

```elixir
keys =
  list_one
  |> Kernel.++(list_two)
  |> get_in([Access.all(), :id])
  |> Enum.uniq()
```

Now we are all set to build the result up.

```elixir
for k <- keys, into: %{} do
  {k,
    %{number_one: Map.get(map_one, k, 0),
      number_two: Map.get(map_two, k, 0)}}  
end
```

Giving us back the desired

```elixir
%{
  a: %{number_one: 1, number_two: 1},
  b: %{number_one: 2, number_two: 4},
  c: %{number_one: 3, number_two: 0},
  d: %{number_one: 0, number_two: 5}
}
```

Comment: Map access is O(log n) :)

Comment: @AdamMillerchip indeed, my hand trembled, fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

I like [Adam's answer the most](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73870861/7682196), but since you said "no maps in either list have more or less keys" and mentioned `Enum.reduce` I figured I'd offer an answer that took both into account! The following solution will only work for two lists, but it is another option.

```
list_one = [
  %{id: :a, value: 1},
  %{id: :b, value: 2},
  %{id: :c, value: 3}
]

list_two = [
  %{id: :a, value: 1},
  %{id: :b, value: 4},
  %{id: :d, value: 5}
]

labels = [:value_one, :value_two]

# Helper function for building a single map out of a list of maps
build_map_with_label = fn acc, map_from_list, label ->
  %{id: id, value: value} = map_from_list

  {_, acc} =
    Map.get_and_update(acc, id, fn current_value ->
      map_from_list =
        if current_value,
          do: current_value,
          else: %{}

      {current_value, Map.put(map_from_list, label, value)}
    end)

  acc
end

# Zip reduce two lists using our map builder helper to produce a single map
Enum.zip_reduce(list_one, list_two, %{}, fn left, right, acc ->
  acc
  |> build_map_with_label.(left, Enum.at(labels, 0))
  |> build_map_with_label.(right, Enum.at(labels, 1))
end)
# This second pass fills in any missing keys with 0
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {id, id_map}, acc ->
  new_id_map =
    Enum.reduce(labels, id_map, fn label, acc ->
      Map.put_new(acc, label, 0)
    end)

  Map.put(acc, id, new_id_map)
end)
|> IO.inspect()
```

Which prints:

```
%{
  a: %{value_one: 1, value_two: 1},
  b: %{value_one: 2, value_two: 4},
  c: %{value_one: 3, value_two: 0},
  d: %{value_one: 0, value_two: 5}
}
```

Comment: You have good taste in answers. ;-) `Enum.zip_reduce/2` is a cool idea, but this can be greatly simplified, I [posted a refactor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73903299/1225617). I think you misunderstood though, because the two lists can have different numbers of elements, so zip will not work in that case.

Comment: You are a legend.  I clearly mis-read "no maps in either list have more or less keys" to suggest that both lists will always have the same number of items.  For OP: like I said, Adam's original answer is what I'd use in any sort of production implementation; I just like coming up with alternative/quirky solutions!

Comment: I use `get_in` all the time but always forget `put_in` exists; excellent! Also how have I never known about [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.14.0/Access.html#key/2)?! That's definitely something I'll consider for future Elixir work. (I don't have enough reputation yet to comment on your other answer or otherwise I would)

Answer (score 0):

This is a refactored version of [Nezteb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73902058/1225617) using [`Enum.zip_reduce/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip_reduce/4), which is a pretty cool approach but just needed to be stripped down to the basics with the help of [`put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3) and [`Access.key/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#key/2). Note that this only works if the two lists have the same number of items.

```elixir
Enum.zip_reduce(list_one, list_two, %{}, fn %{id: id_one, value: value_one},
                                            %{id: id_two, value: value_two},
                                            acc ->
  acc
  |> put_in([Access.key(id_one, %{value_two: 0}), :value_one], value_one)
  |> put_in([Access.key(id_two, %{value_one: 0}), :value_two], value_two)
end)
```

---

Here is a version that uses a similar approach, but without `zip_reduce`, to do it in a single pass of both lists. This works even if the lists are of different length:

```elixir
a =
  for %{id: id, value: value} <- list_one, reduce: %{} do
    acc -> put_in(acc, [Access.key(id, %{value_two: 0}), :value_one], value)
  end

for %{id: id, value: value} <- list_two, reduce: a do
  acc -> put_in(acc, [Access.key(id, %{value_one: 0}), :value_two], value)
end
```